# how to define two values for the enum like below?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

```
export enum visible {
    Me = 73 | 97,
    Team = 74 | 98
}
```

can we define enum in typescript with two values , i have scenario where it should accept both numbers for single enum 'Me'

Comment: In principle, enum can have only one value (I am not sure if Typescript is any different).  But if you need multiple values for an enum, it makes sense to create a class and encapsulate it within.

Comment: @Sid is correct. Enum members cannot have more than one value in typescript. What pattern are you trying to represent here? There is probably a better way.

Answer (score 1):

Enum can not be used like that. I'm not sure what exactly you're trying to do but it seems like you may want to have an interface instead.

For example:

```
export interface Visible {
  Me: 73 | 97;
  Team: 74 | 98;
}

const visible: Visible = { Me: 73, Team: 98 };
```